# create Dynamic columns in maria db using spring boot with jpa

Tags: java, json, jpa, spring-boot, mariadb

I have using maria db to store dynamic columns.In sql Query it is there in the maria db documentation. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns/ .
But i couldn't find a spring boot jpa implementation.I have tried jpa native query.I am storing a Json in this dynamic column which is data type of Blob in maria db.But it is very tough because i couldn't find a way to store when json is nesting another objects or arrays.Is there any way to accomplish this task

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a string.  It could be stored in a `TEXT` or `BLOB` column.

The issue is that it is a structured string and it is tempting to reach into it to inspect/modify fields.  Don't.  It won't be efficient.

Copy values out of the JSON that you need for `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` (etc) so that MySQL/MariaDB can efficiently access them.  Sure, keep copies inside the JSON text/blob, if you like.

Please describe your use for JSON, there may be more tips on "proper" usage inside a database.

That being said, MariaDB 10.2 has picked up much of Oracle's JSON.  But there is not a JSON *datatype*.  And there are a few [*function differences*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/function-differences-between-mariadb-102-and-mysql-57/).

And this does not explain how far behind the 3rd party software (spring-boot, etc) is.